# Problem to extract value from complex_to_mag_squared GNURadio block

Tags: signal-detection, gnuradio, signal-power

I am trying to dissecate a large bandwidth into smaller ones and, for each of those smaller bands, see if it contains enough energy to consider that a message is sent in it. To do so, I am thinking of doing it by implementing the following schematic [image: schematic to implement]

So far, I have been able to implement everythink, except for the `compute threshold` block (aimed at updating the threshold of the various `threshold` blocks). The problem I am facing is that I do not know how to retrieve the value of the different `complex_to_mag_squared` blocks. Does anyone know how to do this ? [Here](https://github.com/aheuchamps/sandbox-repo/blob/main/sweeper.py) is the link to the code I have so far.

Thank you and have a nice day, Alex.

Comment: There's nothing to "retrieve" - they just output magnitude squares on their output. You connect your block to that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MarcusMüller, I will try by simple connection. Have a nice day, Alex

Comment: @MarcusMüller I tried to just print the values given by the `complex_to_mag_squared` block, and was expecting to see some `float` values. Insted, I got something like this
`all_cmpl_to_mag2[0] = <gr_block complex_to_mag_squared (4)>`. I do not understand how to get the value from there ?

Comment: you did not print values, you printed a block. Not how GNU Radio works! The samples are not available at the level where you construct the flow graph – you only interact with them using *blocks*. So, you need to write a block. tutorials.gnuradio.org has a good introduction to doing that :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh okay I thought it was like that I had to do. I am going to search how to access the value rather than access the whole block. Thank you for your answer :D

Comment: I already answered that. You need to write a block.

Comment: Okay will do, thank you

Comment: Hello @MarcusMüller. I am coming back to you because it has been one week now and I still did not manage to write the blocks to make what I want. I have written a block `cmp_avg_pow` which `work` function computes `output_items[0][:] = np.mean( input_items )` (`np` being short for `numpy`) and another block, `custom_thres` which `work` function just make `output_items[0][:] = blocks.threshold_ff(0.0, input_items[-1], 0)`. In my main function, I connect `complex_to_mag_squared` blocks to both `cmp_avg_pow` and `custom_thres`, and the output of `cmp_avg_pow` also to `custom_thres`. Nice day,Alex

Comment: you mustn't do that! Your `np.mean` depends on the length of `input_items`, and that will be different every call. So, this is not the way to go. I don't think this will all fit in the comments here. Would you mind writing an email to the [discuss-gnuradio@gnu.org](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradio) mailing list, with your block code (and because people won't know what we discussed here, a short description of what you want to do!)?